# Problem with Logistic Regression and sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I need to do Logistic Regression using Python, but I have constantly comunicate as below when I try to apply the logistic regression. Please help me, what should I do? I can add that I have already installed sklearn.

C:\Users\John12\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py:432: FutureWarning: Default solver will be changed to 'lbfgs' in 0.22. Specify a solver to silence this warning.
  FutureWarning)

Comment: Please first try something and then post your question here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I solve the future warning -> % (min\_groups, self.n\_splits)), Warning) in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640386/how-do-i-solve-the-future-warning-min-groups-self-n-splits-warning-in)

Answer (score 1):

Go to where you implement your LR and make sure you add the following.
Please provide code next time

```
# create and configure model
model = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, this is a warning. There is a good post about it: [How do I solve the future warning -> % (min_groups, self.n_splits)), Warning) in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640386/how-do-i-solve-the-future-warning-min-groups-self-n-splits-warning-in).

Your warning means that the default solver will change in another version of your library.

One way is to ignore the warning (not recommended):

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)
```

And the other one is to specifiy your solver:

```
model = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
```

When you specified your solver, you will not have the problem that the defaul solver (when you don't specifiy anything) will be changed in the next version...